# SMTP + E2E Encryption per recipient

Tags: smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I don't have much experience with SMTP per se except for a passing familiarity with the basic commands, so I might be overlooking something.

**Would it be possible for server to postpone enabling encryption, until receiving the recipient address from client, and only then retrieving the public key for the recipient based on the address and enabling encryption based on that?** Then the server should only have access to the subject, and the client could decrypt it themselves with their private key.

I would think that if this were possible, it would be the standard. Yet, I don't see anyone doing it, and it's not clear to me why it's not possible.